# Acumatica Excel Import doing nothing, how do I troubleshoot?

Tags: acumatica

Have the import button showing up fine, launches the dialog, yet when go through the steps, nothing visible imported.

Where/How might I determine what I need to change?

Very rough summary:

- Have PXImport attribute declared, with the base graph primary view
  (which is NOT redefined)
- Have AllowUpload set
- Dialog for selection of
  form, mapping of fields, etc DOES show up
- Grid unpopulated after final dialog box

Some things have already tried:

- Altering the PXImport to the name of the DAC (no change)
- Altering the Key to be the imported LotSerialNbr (no change)

DAC (extension to SOShipmentEntry)

```
[PXCopyPasteHiddenView]
**[PXImport(typeof(SOShipment))]**
public PXSelect<MQMJSOShipmentEntryExtScanLabel> MQMJSOShipmentEntryExtScanLabels;
```

Intention is for the table to be unbound, yet that seems to mess up other things.  So I've created a table that should never be written to
partial DAC:

```
public class MQMJSOShipmentEntryExtScanLabel : PX.Data.IBqlTable
{
    #region LineNbr

    public abstract class lineNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }

    protected Guid? _LineNbr;

     [PXGuid(**IsKey = true**)]
    //[PXGuid()]
    public virtual Guid? LineNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LineNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LineNbr = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion LineNbr

    #region LotSerialNbr

    public abstract class lotSerialNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }

    protected string _LotSerialNbr;

    //[PXDBString(100,IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXDefault("", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Lot Serial Number")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search5<INLotSerialStatus.lotSerialNbr,
        InnerJoin<SOShipLine, On<SOShipLine.inventoryID,Equal<INLotSerialStatus.inventoryID>, And<SOShipLine.locationID,Equal<INLotSerialStatus.locationID>>>>,
        Where<INLotSerialStatus.qtyOnHand, Greater<decimal0>, And<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>
            >>,Aggregate<GroupBy<INLotSerialStatus.lotSerialNbr, Max<INLotSerialStatus.qtyAvail>>>>),
        new Type[] { typeof(INLotSerialStatus.lotSerialNbr), typeof(INLotSerialStatus.qtyAvail) })]
    public virtual string LotSerialNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LotSerialNbr;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LotSerialNbr = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion PlantID
```

Partial page code:

```
<px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="MQMJSOShipmentEntryExtScanLabelPopup" DesignView="Content" TabIndex="13700" Width="800px" LoadOnDemand="True" CreateOnDemand="True" AutoReload="True" AutoRepaint="True" CaptionVisible="True" Caption="Scan Labels to Ship" AlreadyLocalized="False" Key="MQMJSOShipmentEntryExtScanLabels">
    <px:PXGrid ID="PXGridMQMJSOShipmentEntryExtScanLabel" runat="server" Width="100%" DataSourceID="ds" AutoAdjustColumns="true" Caption="Shipped Items" Height="240px" AllowFilter="False" SkinID="Details" CaptionVisible="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSearch="True" AdjustPageSize="Auto" SyncPosition="true">
        <**Mode AllowUpload="True"** InitNewRow="false"/>
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="MQMJSOShipmentEntryExtScanLabels" DataKeyNames="LotSerialNbr">
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LotSerialNbr" AutoCallBack="true"/>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID" AutoCallBack="true"/>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID_InventoryItem_Descr" AutoCallBack="true"/>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="QtyShip" AutoCallBack="true"/>
                </Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
    </px:PXGrid>
    <px:PXPanel runat="server" ID="PXPanel43A57822CF0444CF5ABE29C6CBD06F100" SkinID="Buttons" Height="50px">
        <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="PXButton43A57822CF0444CF5ABE29C6CBD06F100" Text="Ship" DialogResult="OK">
            <AutoCallBack Target="ds" Command="Commit">
                <Behavior CommitChanges="True" PostData="Content"/>
            </AutoCallBack>
        </px:PXButton>
        <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="PXButton53A57822CF0444CF5ABE29C6CBD06F100" Text="Cancel" DialogResult="Cancel"/>
    </px:PXPanel>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
```

Comment: Could be due to your key field value and providing a value. If using LineNbr then you need a defaulting value to give each line a key. Otherwise LotSerialNbr should work as long as its unique for a key during import. I think the problem is the cached values during import cannot be stored by key. Also you can find examples in source usages of PrepareImportRow which allows you to adjust the data as to which is actually a key in your import vs the DAC key

Comment: Good ideas, the WithDefaulting was set when the GUID was used as key, and the LotSerialNbr is unique (well, unique enough..).  Hoping to avoid the PrepareImportRow since I don't (hopefully) need to do anything with the excel file/data, should be 1:1 with all columns matching

Answer (score 0):

Per an Acumatica development case, their workaround is to **put the grid on a tab rather than a pop up**, and then *train users to hit the grid refresh button in order to see the imported info*.
Still working on the need to click refresh, thought might be able to fix through .aspx changes

Comment: Bah, confirmed bug that only the last record gets imported this way (e.g. have Excel doc with 3 rows, only the last gets into the grid after import).

Comment: PFA the working package and the sample file used for your reference. After investigating further, I was able to understand that the issue happens because of the key field not properly set. So, I have modified the Line Nbr to have PXLineNbr attribute and make use of a new line counter value added in SOShipmentExtn. 

Now, that it is properly configured, I have also set CommitChanges to True for LineNbr and it seems to import all the line items without any issues. And to automatically refresh the grid on completion of upload, have unchecked AdjustPageSize property for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Due to bug in 22r1, prior answer just won't work (I need the import feature, expect 100+ records per use)

So, in the pop up, I've added:
Currently using a direct excel import button, thanks to Sergey

- https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/03/process-file-in-memory.html
  (PXUploadDialog)
- https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/03/reading-excel-file-acumatica.html